# Multiple columns in QUERY with "and" in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

How to choose 2 columns in QUERY instead of one to search for specified values? The current formula searches only one Col4, I need to search **both Col4 and Col5** in the highlighted places on the screen 1.

For clarity, let's take a screenshot 2 of the "Data" sheet. In the current formula, the output is only for column 4 (red colour on screen), but how do I make the output for both column 4 and column 5 (blue colour on screen)? I tried different options, including inserting "or", but it didn't work

Screenshot 1
[image]

Screenshot 2
[image]

Formula in A7:

```
=QUERY({Data!A2:E}," where (Col4='"& B1&"' or Col5='"& B1&"') "&IFS(
C3,"and Col2='"& B3&"'"&IF( C2,"and Col4='"& B2&"'",)&"",
E3,"and Col2='"& D3&"'",C2,"and Col4='"& B2&"'",
NOT(AND(E3,C3))," "      &IF( C2,"and Col4='"& B2&"'",)&"")&"")
```

Comment: The significance of Col4 and Col5 is unclear. Would you please edit your question to 1) explain the outcome you are trying to achieve (i.e. the significance of Column 4 and Col5), 2) provide sample data (as text) and 3) provide an example of successful outcome.

Comment: Use an `OR` condition.

Comment: @Tedinoz  I have corrected and supplemented the task a little bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer:

```
=QUERY({Data!A2:E},"where (Col4='"& B1&"' or Col5='"& B1&"') "&IFS(
C3,"and Col2='"& B3&"'"&IF( C2,"and (Col4='"&B2&"' or Col5='"&B2&"')",)&"",
E3,"and Col2='"& D3&"'",      C2,"and (Col4='"&B2&"' or Col5='"&B2&"')",
NOT(AND(E3,C3))," "      &IF( C2,"and (Col4='"&B2&"' or Col5='"&B2&"')",)&"")&"")
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).